# jQuery: Inverse intersection (filtering) of JSON array 1 by values in JSON array 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have 2 JSON arrays which are actually the key and value pairs for 2 different select elements.

The 'left' select is of 'available' users whereas the 'right' select is of 'existing' users.

What I want to do is filter the first JSON array by the keys (index is sufficient) removing any key/value pairs from JSON array 1 that are in JSON array 2.

Here are the two sample JSON arrays;

```
Object {1: "Stephen Grant", 112: "Joan Smith", 221: "Trent Renshaw", 302: "Jane Doe", 430: "Aimee Hudspeth", 508: "John Smith"}

Object {212: "John Citizen", 221: "Trent Renshaw", 302: "Jane Doe"}
```

The resultant JSON array should look like this:

```
Object {1: "Stephen Grant", 112: "Joan Smith", 430: "Aimee Hudspeth", 508: "John Smith"}
```

It looks like a task for $.grep and/or $.each and/or $.inArray but I can't seem to 'get it right'.

Cheers,
Trent.

Comment: these are not arrays these are Objects.

Comment: Correct, these are now JSON representations of what was a PHP array.

Comment: I've added an answer which should work for you.

Comment: @TrentRenshaw You do understand that these data structures are not JSON *arrays*, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach I took, and turned it into a function, as I need to use in a number of places i.e. filtering one select by options in another select. Hopefully this will be of use to others:-

```
function filterSelect(valuesObj, valuesToRemoveObj) {

    $.each(valuesToRemoveObj, function(n, i) {
        if($.inArray(n, valuesObj)) {
            delete valuesObj[n];
        }
    });

    return valuesObj;
}
```

Cheers,
Trent.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
var d1 = {
    1: "Stephen Grant",
    112: "Joan Smith",
    221: "Trent Renshaw",
    302: "Jane Doe",
    430: "Aimee Hudspeth",
    508: "John Smith"
};

var d2 = {
    212: "John Citizen",
    221: "Trent Renshaw",
    302: "Jane Doe"
};

var d3 = {};
for (var key in d1) {
    if (d1.hasOwnProperty(key) && !d2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // possibly check for duplicates you get the idea
        d3[key] = d1[key];
    }
};
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vBP9S/)

Comment: This is approach is not so elegant and the solution sought is to use jQuery. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That are not arrays those are objects.

This should work for you with jQuery

```
var first = {1: "Stephen Grant", 112: "Joan Smith", 221: "Trent Renshaw", 302: "Jane Doe", 430: "Aimee Hudspeth", 508: "John Smith"}

var second = {212: "John Citizen", 221: "Trent Renshaw", 302: "Jane Doe"}

var result = {};

$.each(first,function (key,value) {
    if(!second[key])
        result[key] = value;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes, it will probably do the trick but per as the question states, I am chasing the jQuery way not the pure Javascript way (as this is only a small part of a much larger jQuery snippet).

Comment: @TrentRenshaw updated my answer using Jquery, according what I know.

Comment: not quite. This leaves result with just 1 value;

    Object {212: "John Citizen"}

Comment: @TrentRenshaw, where did you tried it's working for me.